# Powershell Diskspace Report with additional Message to Display when Server is not available

Tags: sql, powershell, report, diskspace

Being a beginner in Powershell I am finding it hard to get my requirement met. I had taken a Powershell Diskspace report script from Microsoft Script repository and modified it as per my requirement and necessity. But I want to add one more exception.

Since I am running the scrpt over a list of Servers, sometimes some servers are not available, and the Powershell script even when the Server is unavailable calculates and gives me a 0% output as i had set the parameters with 16% as critical and 20% as warning.
I had tried to fiddle around with some if and else condition but not able to get the desired result.

What I need is:-
When the Server is not available, instead of the calculation happening, make it display a message below the server name, example;

```
HDJT-003
```

"Server Unavailable, please check"

WIll be really grateful if someone can give me a push.

**Below is the modified Powershell script, it works perfectly fine:-**

```
$freeSpaceFileName = "C:\reports\Drive Space Report\Drive_Space_Report.html"
$titleDate = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y - %A" 
$serverlist = "C:\reports\Drive Space Report\Server.txt" 
$warning = 20 
$critical = 16 
New-Item -ItemType file $freeSpaceFileName -Force 

$tableDescription = " 
 </table><br><table width='30%' align= 'center'> 
 <tr bgcolor='White'> 
    <td width='20%' align='center' bgcolor='#FBB917'>Warning less than 20% free space</td> 
 <td width='20%' align='center' bgcolor='#FF0000'>Critical less than 16% free space</td> 
 </tr> 
" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName $tableDescription 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</body></html>"

Function writeHtmlHeader 
{ 
param($fileName) 
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') 
Add-Content $fileName "<html>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<head>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>" 
Add-Content $fileName '<title>Your Company Servers DiskSpace Report</title>' 
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">' 
add-content $fileName  "<!--" 
add-content $fileName  "td {" 
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;" 
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "}" 
add-content $fileName  "body {" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;" 
add-content $fileName  "" 
add-content $fileName  "table {" 
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;" 
add-content $fileName  "}" 
add-content $fileName  "-->" 
add-content $fileName  "</style>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</head>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<body>" 

add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Your Company Servers DiskSpace Report - $date</strong></font>" 
add-content $fileName  "</td>" 
add-content $fileName  "</tr>" 
add-content $fileName  "</table>" 

} 

Function writeTableHeader 
{ 
param($fileName) 

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Drive</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
} 

Function writeHtmlFooter 
{ 
param($fileName) 

Add-Content $fileName "</body>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</html>" 
} 

Function writeDiskInfo 
{ 
param($fileName,$devId,$volName,$frSpace,$totSpace) 
$totSpace=[math]::Round(($totSpace/1073741824),2) 
$frSpace=[Math]::Round(($frSpace/1073741824),2) 
$usedSpace = $totSpace - $frspace 
$usedSpace=[Math]::Round($usedSpace,2) 
$freePercent = ($frspace/$totSpace)*100 
$freePercent = [Math]::Round($freePercent,0) 
 if ($freePercent -gt $warning) 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 

 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$freePercent</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
 elseif ($freePercent -le $critical) 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>$freePercent</td>" 
 #<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center> 
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FBB917' align=center>$freePercent</td>" 
 # #FBB917 
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
} 
writeHtmlHeader $freeSpaceFileName 
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{ 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server </strong></font></td>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>" 

writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName 

$dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} 
foreach ($item in $dp) 
{ 
Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 
writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 

 } 
} 


writeHtmlFooter $freeSpaceFileName 
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')


$smtpServer = "SMTP SERVER" 
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$msg.To.Add("xyz@xyz.com")
$msg.To.Add("xyz@xyz.com")
$msg.CC.Add("xyz@xyz.com")
$emailattachment= "C:\reports\Drive Space Report\Drive_Space_Report.html"
       $msg.From = "sqlserver@globalpay.com" 
$msg.Subject = "Your Statement Report for $titledate" 
    #$body = Get-Content $freeSpaceFileName
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($emailattachment, 'text/plain')
   $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
      $msg.Body = get-content $freeSpaceFileName 
$smtp.Send($msg)

exit
go
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use a try/catch block or something like this:

```powershell
$dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3}

If($dp){ 
    foreach ($item in $dp) 
    { 
        Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 
        writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 
    }
} Else {
        writeNAInfo $server    
}
```

We have inserted `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` so if there is an error collecting information or there are no disks matching the criteria `$dp` would be empty.

Using a simple `if` we check for results and if there is none then you would be able to add line in you output as you desire.

You will need to make the function `writeNAInfo` in order to make the table row you desire.

**Welcome to SO**

FYI You have too much code here that has **no** relation to the source of your question. In the future try and put only the code necessary to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{
    if (test-connection -computername $server -quiet)
    {
        do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Couldn't connect to $server."
    }
}
```

You can also use the -Count switch of Test-Connection reduce the number of pings i.e.

```
 -Count 1
```

will run much quicker.

Comment: I want the output to be shown in the report, as this script is for the output to be mailed, part of an automation.

This additiion shows the result only on the powershell screen?

Comment: Then instead of write-host just add a line to the file that you're sending as an attachment.